# Open workspace browser + working directory in rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I don't know what happened, but when I start rstudio, it's only opening the concsole window. I am missing the workspace browser window an the working directory window.

Can you guys tell me how to open them? I can't find anything on the internet.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes these windows are inadvertently minimized. There is a small gripper on the right side of the window which will restore them. This article should make it clear:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213238798-Restoring-Missing-Help-Environment-Plot-Panes